# Microsoft Access 2010: Using data from a text box within an SQL update statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to call the data stored in a text box on a form within an SQL statement?  I have placed the following statement within the RunSQL action following the SaveRecord action of my button.

```
UPDATE (Material 
INNER JOIN [Transaction] ON Material.Material = Transaction.Material)
INNER JOIN Ordered ON Transaction.[No] = Ordered.[No]
WHERE [Forms]![Order Material]![textBox_No] = Transaction.[No]
SET Material.[On Order] = [On Order]+[Amount];
```

I am trying to pull the data stored in a text box (*textBox_No*) on my form (*Order Material*) and compare it to the results pulled by the update query.  I only want *On Order* to be updated if the data in *textBox_No* is equal to the *No* field of *Transaction*.

When I click my button, the data entered in  the form updates properly, however when the SQL statement goes to run it gives me a syntax error.

#### Research

I've tried to find syntax guides for an update query, however Microsoft's website only gives examples for [the select query type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-access-sql-HA010341468.aspx#BM8).  I did find what I thought would be a helpful guide to [pulling data out of a text box on a form](http://www.upsizing.co.uk/Art25_QueryByForm.aspx), however the guide is for a much older version of Microsoft Access than I am using.  This guide is where I got `[Forms]![Order Material]![textBox_No]` which I am trying to use to pull the data out of the text box.

Comment: [Here is a screenshot](http://i41.tinypic.com/mt59w1.png) of how I have configured the button on the form.  The picture might explain how I set up the button better than I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHERE clause must come after the SET clause.  Also, "Transaction" is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) so it must be enclosed in square brackets throughout.

```
UPDATE (Material 
INNER JOIN [Transaction] ON Material.Material = [Transaction].Material)
INNER JOIN Ordered ON [Transaction].[No] = Ordered.[No]
SET Material.[On Order] = [On Order]+[Amount]
WHERE [Forms]![Order Material]![textBox_No] = [Transaction].[No];
```

It's good practice (and just generally makes life easier) to avoid naming tables and fields with reserved words.  Refer to the link above for a complete list of reserved words.

Comment: Odd, Access did not complain when I set Transaction as my table name.  I'll keep the reserved words list in mind in the future though.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Nope, Access won't complain.  You can name your tables anything you like: `Select`, `From`, `Where`, `Order By`, etc.  But Access will complain as soon as you start trying to use those names in queries and other places.  You'll drive yourself crazy with square brackets everywhere.

Comment: @mwolfe02 Access used not to complain, in 2010, it started complaining. If you try to use `name` you get a message, but not for `transaction`.

Comment: There is no problem in an Access query with the word `transaction` : `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, Transaction FROM Transaction")`

Comment: @Remou: Good info. I've not used Access 2010 yet; the warning seems like an appropriate improvement.

Comment: @Remou: Interesting that `Transaction` causes no problems.  It is listed as a Jet 4.0 Reserved Word: [List of reserved words in Jet 4.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738)

Comment: @mwolfe02 And so it is, you cannot use `transaction` against a query run using ADODB, but you can run with DAO in Access.